# In Yocto, how to read a git repository via ssh on a nonstandard port

Tags: git, yocto

I created a recipe containing these definitions:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git:<password>@<ip address>:<ssh_port>/home/git/tuxin-repo/project.git;protocol=ssh;branch=test"
SRCREV_default = "5a0b8545d39c97bd9f9628143ed174dabb71f641"
```

bitbake ends with errors

> ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128,
>   output: Cloning into bare repository
>   '/home/yocto/build/downloads/git2/..home.git.tuxin-repo.project.git'...
>   Permission denied, please try again. Permission denied, please try
>   again. Permission denied (publickey,password). fatal: Could not read
>   from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.
>
> ERROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure for URL:
>   'git://git:@:/home/git/tuxin-repo/project.git;protocol=ssh;branch='test''.
>   Unable to fetch URL from any source. ERROR: Logfile of failure stored
>   in:
>   /home/yocto/build/tmp/work/cortexa8hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/capsystem/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.7045
>   ERROR: Task 4
>   (/home/yocto/sources/poky/../meta-tuxin/recipes-support/project/project.bb,
>   do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'

while in command line, and after typing the password, the project is loaded.

```
git clone --branch test ssh://git@<ip_address>:<ssh_port>/home/git/tuxin-repo/project.git
```

Can someone explain to me my mistake?

Comment: Did you try to add user,password and port in parameters after protocol=ssh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the SRC_URI in this way:

```
SRC_URI = "git://git@<ip address>:<ssh_port>/home/git/tuxin-repo/project.git;protocol=ssh;branch=test"
```

Note the use of **git@** before the IP address. You cannot specify the password in the SRC_URI as a security measure. For automatic authentication you will have to use other methods as .ssh/config